# Sql hashed varbinary producing different results

Tags: sql-server, hash, sql-server-2014

I have a table in SQL Server 2014 with following columns:

```
ID (PK, int, not null) 
filecontent (varbinary(max), not null) 
filecontenthashed (computed, binay(16), null) => ([sys].[fn_repl_hash_binary](filecontent))
```

I store files as `bytes[]` in this table and use the hashed column to check for duplicates.

Running a select statement, it returns the computed column.

However when I inserted the same file 3 times (exactly the same file), I noticed the computed column is returning different hashed values.

```
FileContent                                FileContentHashed
0x255044462D312E350A25C7EC8FA20A35203...   0x71E2322C77CAFFCDF3E427D7BF6537E3
0x255044462D312E350A25C7EC8FA20A35203...   0x16E142FEAA996B38413B87023A651E28
0x255044462D312E350A25C7EC8FA20A35203...   0x1F02D564F0A550C9FAF913A023B6C2EA
```

Any idea or suggestion why its not returning the same value?

I am using this function for the computed column

```
([sys].[fn_repl_hash_binary](filecontent))
```

Also, my file is bigger than 8000 bytes

Comment: Undocumented functions have undocumented behaviors. Have you tried something like `hashbytes()` or `checksum()`?

Answer (score 2):

### `HASHBYTES` function

Here is an example of your table definition.

```
ID (PK, int, not null) 
filecontent (varbinary(max), not null) 
filecontenthashed (computed, binay(16), null) => (HASHBYTES('MD5', filecontent))
```

These are the possible algorithms you can put :

> MD2 | MD4 | MD5 | SHA | SHA1 | SHA2_256 | SHA2_512

Documentation says that input can use varbinary

> @input Specifies a variable containing the data to be hashed. @input
>   is varchar, nvarchar, or varbinary.

Also I would suggest you using a `PERSISTED` computed column for performances issues.

### SQL Version Limitations and circumvention

By the way, make sure you migrate on SQL 2016 or later for this solution to work
(if your data input goes above 8KB)

> For SQL Server 2014 and earlier, allowed input values are limited to
>   8000 bytes.

If migrating on SQL 2016 is an issue, you may consider using [`CHECKSUM` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql).

#### References

[HASHBYTES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql)
[COMPUTED COLUMN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql)

Comment: Problem is the data can be grater than 8k bytes, so your solution does not work as hashbytes can only process less than 8k bytes.

Comment: I commented the solution with the limitations on SQL 2014 and earlier versions. This solution only works for SQL 2016 and later.